# Declaration of strings in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c)
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

There is something I don't understand about strings and pointers in C.

Suppose I have this declaration:

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

Then, if I attempt to modify it this way:

```
str[0] = 'b';
```

It will work.

But if I declare the string as a pointer to a char

```
char* str = "abc"
```

The attempt above will cause an access violation.

What I'm trying to understand is what exactly is the difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please search before asking - this has to have been answered 50K times here (plus 20M more on the interwebs)

Answer (score 0):

In The later example the compiler puts the string in the read only data section, so u can't modify it. But in earlier example you are declaring array of character which resides in stack hence you can modify content of this array.