# C++ Swap string

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a non-recursive method to swap a c-style string. It throws an exception in the Swap method. Could not figure out the problem.

```
void Swap(char *a, char* b)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void Reverse_String(char * str, int length)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i <= length/2; i++)  //do till the middle
    {
        Swap(str+i, str+length - i);

    }

}
```

EDIT: I know there are fancier ways to do this. But since I'm learning, would like to know the problem with the code.

Comment: What is the "exception"?  Do you mean it crashes?  Did you use a debugger?  What input did you use that caused it to crash?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example (I suggest using ideone.com) that compiles correctly and fails when run?

Comment: It crashes. EXC_BAD_ACCESS in swap

Comment: what string do you reverse? where do you call your function

Comment: Sounds like you are feeding it a constant string laying in a memory part you are not allowed to modify...or you have a off by one error (`str+length` should perhaps be `str+length-1`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It throws an exception in the Swap method. Could not figure out the problem.

No it doesn't.  Creating a temporary character and assigning characters can not possibly throw an exception.  You might have an access violation, though, if your pointers don't point to blocks of memory you own.

The `Reverse_String()` function looks OK, assuming `str` points to at least `length` bytes of writable memory.  There's not enough context in your question to extrapolate past that.  I suspect you are passing invalid parameters.  You'll need to show how you call `Reverse_String()` for us to determine if the call is valid or not.

If you are writing something like this:

```
char * str = "Foo";
Reverse_String(str, 3);
printf("Reversed: '%s'.\n", str);
```

Then you will definitely get an access violation, because `str` points to read-only memory.  Try the following syntax instead:

```
char str[] = "Foo";
Reverse_String(str, 3);
printf("Reversed: '%s'.\n", str);
```

This will actually make a copy of the `"Foo"` string into a local buffer you can overwrite.

Comment: oh! I was doing the former. What exactly is the difference between `char str[] = "Foo";` and `char* str = "Foo"` ?

Comment: Where can i read more on this. Differences between char* char[] string and std::string?

Comment: You can read more in these related questions: [Why does simple C code receive segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault) [Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

This answer refers to the comment by @user963018 made under @André Caron's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541874/c-swap-string/7541920#7541920) (it's too long to be a comment).

```
char *str = "Foo";
```

The above declares a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`. The array is 4 characters long, 3 for `F`, `o` & `o` and 1 for a terminating NULL character. The array itself is stored in memory marked as read-only; which is why you were getting the access violation. In fact, in C++, your declaration is deprecated (it is allowed for backward compatibility to C) and your compiler should be warning you as such. If it isn't, try turning up the warning level. You should be using the following declaration:

```
const char *str = "Foo";
```

Now, the declaration indicates that `str` should not be used to modify whatever it is pointing to, and the compiler will complain if you attempt to do so.

```
char str[] = "Foo";
```

This declaration states that `str` is a array of 4 characters (including the NULL character). The difference here is that `str` is of type `char[N]` (where N == 4), not `char *`. However, `str` can *decay* to a pointer type if the context demands it, so you can pass it to the `Swap` function which expects a `char *`. Also, the memory containing `Foo` is no longer marked read-only, so you can modify it.

```
std::string str( "Foo" );
```

This declares an object of type `std::string` that contains the string "Foo". The memory that contains the string is dynamically allocated by the string object as required (some implementations may contain a small private buffer for small string optimization, but forget that for now). If you have string whose size may vary, or whose size you do not know at compile time, it is best to use `std::string`.