# Reversing a C string function crashes?

Tags: c, string, return, reverse

I'm trying to write a C function to reverse a passed in C style string (ie char *) and return the char pointer of the reversed string. But when I run this in VS2012, nothing is printed in terminal and "main.exe has stopped working" msg shows up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char * rrev_str(char * str )
{
    char *revd_str=""; //I tried char revd_str []="" error: stack around "revd_str" is corrupted
    int i,r;
    int str_len=strlen(str);
    for (i = str_len-1, r=0; i >=0; i--,r++)
    {
        revd_str[r]= str[i];
    }
    return revd_str;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char str1 [] ="STEETS";
   char str2 [] ="smile everyday!";

   //reverse "chars" in a C string and return it
   char * rev_string=rrev_str(str1);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784099/why-does-this-small-c-program-crash/8784124#8784124

Same problem as this one ..

Comment: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'revd_str' was corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is three fold. First you aren't allocating enough space for the reversed string, and secondly you are returning a pointer to a local variable in rrev_str(), and thirdly you're modifying a string literal. You need to allocate space for revd_str on the heap:

```
char * rrev_str(char * str )
{   
    int i,r;
    int str_len=strlen(str);

    char *revd_str=malloc(str_len + 1); 
    memset(revd_str, 0, str_len + 1);

    for (i = str_len-1, r=0; i >=0; i--,r++)
    {
        revd_str[r]= str[i];
    }
    return revd_str;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to assign the terminator as well, as malloc doesn't guarentee a zero'ed memory location.

Comment: Thanks that worked. With 1 small syntax edit: memset's 3rd arg expects a variable and no other operation done with that var when passed thru. so instead of str_len+1, it expects a single variable storing this val. So I put str_len+1 in a temp_var and passed it to memset

Comment: Yes it will work. But you need to free heap memory when it is not require. It may be memory leak if you not free it in future.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

You are accessing invalid memory address.
`revd_str` is pointing to literal constant string of length 1 and you are accessing it beyond the length which is invalid.

**Solution:**

- Create char array of require length (statically or dynamically).
- Reverse the given string.
- Pass 2nd param as destination string

   syntax: `char * rrev_str(char * src, char *dest);`

**Reverse the given string**

```
char * rrev_str(char * str )
{
   int start = 0;
   int end = strlen(str) - 1;
   char temp;

    for (; start < end; start++ ,end--)
    {
        temp = str[start];
        str[start] = str[end];
        str[end] = temp;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char string [] ="smile";

   //reverse "chars" in a C string and return it
   char * rev_string = rrev_str(string);

   printf("%s",rev_string);
}
```

**Pass 2nd param as destination string**

```
char * rrev_str(char * src, char *dest)
{
   int srcLength = strlen(src);
   int destLength = strlen(dest);
   int i;
   // Invalid destination string
   if (srcLength > destLength)
   {
        return NULL;
   }

   dest[srcLength] = '\0';
   srcLength--;
    for (i=0; srcLength >= 0;i++, srcLength--)
    {
        dest[i] = src[srcLength];
    }

 return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char string [] ="smile";
   char revString[20];  

   //reverse "chars" in a C string and return it
   char * rev_string = rrev_str(string, revString);

    printf("%s",rev_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What! you are doing..

```
char *revd_str=""; // Creating String Literal which can't be modified because they are read only  
char *revd_str[]=""; // Creating Char Array of Size Zero.
```

### So Solution are

Either take reference of your string

```
char *revd_str = strdup(str);
```

Or create dynamic char array

```
char *revd_str = (char*) malloc (strlen(str)+1);
```

your program will run fine. logic is incorrect for reversing so modify it. A sample solution is given below

```
char * rrev_str(char * str )
{
    char *revd_str=strdup(str);
    int i;  // no need for extra 'int r'
    int str_len=strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < str_len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = revd_str[i];
        revd_str[i]= revd_str[str_len - 1 -i];
        revd_str[str_len - 1 -i] = temp;
    }
    return revd_str;
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps use `strdup` to get a duplicate of the same size. Also, `char *revd_str=str` does not create a copy of str, it overwrites str.

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. I was taken wrong it as change in given string. I have corrected it.