# Are string literals constant or not?

Tags: c, c-strings, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c)

```
char *s = "anusha";
```

Is this like a constant pointer? When i tried to change the character in location 3 by writing `s[3]='k'`, it gave me a segmentation fault. So i am assuming it is like pointing to a constant array or s is a constant pointer? Which among the two? Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct, you are not allowed to modify string literals.

However, it's legal to do this:

```
char s[] = "anusha";
s[3] = 'k'
```

The difference here being that it is stored as a local array that can be modified.

Comment: Thanks.But is it a constant array or a constant pointer? Neither of them ?

Comment: In your example, the pointer isn't constant, but you still aren't allowed to modify it. In the example in my answer, it's the same as any locally declared array.

Comment: The *formal type* of the array is `char []` (no `const`), but attempts to modify it result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your compiler treats `"anusha"` as a pointer to `char`, but places the string itself into write-protected memory. I remember reading that this is a convenience policy in order to comply with existing code.

As Joe pointed out, this is detailed in [Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c).

Comment: Here's a practical reason: Any time "anusha" appears as a literal, the compiler can just use the same address.  This won't be valid if it is allowed to be changed.

Comment: @Michael So as i read in another similar post...... if i said    char *s="anusha"; and printf("anusha"); later somewhere in the code, the compiler uses the same string literal address in both the statements? Does that mean it checks if such a string literal already exists?

Comment: That's a reason for write-protecting it, but not for making it `char*` instead of `const char*`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now.  And I didn't know that.  Interestingly, apparently in c it is char[], (not char*), and in c++ the type is const char*.  The reason for char[] instead of char* is that sizeof will give you the size of the string this way.