# Converting char* to lower case throws segfault error

Tags: c, pointers, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c)

I have a function to convert a char* to lower case. This is the function:

```
void toLower(char* word, int length)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // this I can do
        // printf("%c", tolower(word[i]));

        // this throws segfault
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
}
```

When I call it like this from main, it throws a segfault error:

```
char* needle = "foobar";
toLower(needle, strlen(needle));
```

I'm certain the issue is in the assignment here:

```
word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
```

But I can't seem to figure out the corect way to do it. I tried passing it as `char**`, or doing `*(word+i)`, but all cause the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are attempting to *change* the constant string `"foobar"`. Try:

```
char needle[] = "foobar";
```

This will create an *array* containing the string `"foobar"` (the compiler arranges to copy the data from the constant string `"foobar"` to your array `needle` where you can modify it).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a string literal. You can create a dynamic string:

```
char *str = strdup(needle);
toLower(str, strlen(str));
/* ... */
free(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `char *needle = "foobar"` is a string literal -- it's a const char. In order the compiler to generate a writable string, use

```
char needle[] = "foobar";
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a string literal is not possible. 
You can do this

```
 word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
```

only in two cases, either

```
char needle[] = "foobar";
```

or
first create memory for char * using malloc and then assign a string to it, like this

```
char * str = (char *) malloc(size0f(char)*10);
strcpy(str,"foobar");
```

Now you can use this