# Why C program crashes?

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-literals

Please, someone explain why the following C program crashes:

```
void changeChar(char *string);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *test = "word";
  changeChar(test);
  return 0;
}

void changeChar(char *string) {
  *string = 'A';
}
```

while the following code works perfectly:

```
void changeChar(char *string);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char test[] = "word";
  changeChar(test);
  return 0;
}

void changeChar(char *string) {
  *string = 'A';
}
```

Comment: Because `test[]` is a character array, while the first `test` is just a character pointer.

Comment: @NullPointerException You are not aware the idea of "constants", are you.

Comment: ("avare of", of course. Damn 5-minute editing limit.)

Comment: @H2CO3, can you be more precise about me missing some constant concepts?

Comment: @NullPointerException I meant, their existence as such. But this question (I mean your comment) shows that in fact you aren't, you just didn't know that string literals were constant (which is somewhat surprising for me, since they are almost always (incorrectly) referred to as "string constants").

Comment: @H2CO3 you may think as you like and instead of pointing and repeating the same thing you could better provide a resource to liquidate my "ignorance" and so that I could be 100% sure that yes, smth is wrong in my vision of string literals

Comment: @H2CO3 In C, string literals are not constants ... thus, you can assign them to pointers to non-const char. Of course, if you write to them, the result is UB, but that's a different matter. (Another matter is why anyone would want to use such a defectively specified language.)

Comment: @MrLister Wrong and irrelevant. E.g., `char x; char* test = &x; changeChar(test);` works fine even though "test is just a character pointer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
char *test = "word";
```

is not the same as

```
char test[] = "word";
```

The first one is *string literal* it MUST not be changed - changing it causes *undefined behavior* (as they are immutable).

The second one is a standard (mutable) array of `char`s.

<strike>By the way, the first one *must* be `const char*`, not `char*` (and this will even solve the issue - you'll get compile time error)</strike> <sub>(thanks to @ouah and  @dasblinkenlight - didn't know, that there's a difference in this case)</sub>

Comment: It must in C++ but not in C where the string literal is immutable but its type is `char[N]` and not `const char[N]`.

Comment: I does not have to be `const char*` in C, only in C++.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Technically. But no sane programmer ever writes `char *justBecauseItsNotRequiredIDontConstQualifyIt = "breakthis";`

Comment: "as they are immutable" -- uh, no. Whether they are "immutable" is *undefined*, which is precisely why storing into them is *undefined behavior*. "But no sane programmer ever writes ..." -- wrong; sane (arguably) programmers have been known to write into string constants on systems where they known to be writable (e.g., M$ implementations with the flags set to allow writable string constants). I recently worked on some legacy code that did exactly that ... I didn't change it because it had been working for 18 years.

Answer (score 5):

The first program crashes because it tries to write the memory allocated to a string literal, which is an undefined behavior. The second program *copies* the string literal into writable memory, fixing the problem.

Comment: +1 for explaining what happens in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

Because `char *test = "word";` defines a pointer to constant string literal that resides within the read-only memory. Trying to modify it results in ***undefined behavior***.

Also have a look at:
[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/1168156)

And since this is quite common mistake, you'll find many duplicates:
[Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164194/1168156)
[C: differences between char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335786/1168156)
[Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011455/1168156)