# Trying to remove the last character in a char array in C

Tags: c, string, arrays, null-terminated

So I wrote the following method:

```
void removeEndingColon(char *charArrayWithColon) {
    // remove ':' from variableName
    size_t indexOfNullTerminator = strlen(charArrayWithColon);
    charArrayWithColon[indexOfNullTerminator - 1] = '\0'; // replace ':' with '\0'
}
```

But when I test it with the following code in eclipse, I get no output and I don't know why my executable isn't able to run.

```
char *charArray1 = "ThisHasAColonAtTheEnd:";
removeEndingColon(charArray1);
```

Comment: What do you mean by no output and what do you mean by not able to tun what is the exact error you get

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Comment: It says my .exe file isn't able to run.

Comment: Does it say just "your .exe isn't able to run" ? That's a very bad error message indeed.

Comment: Please describe the ***exact*** error message. It would help if you describe your platform, (Linux/Windows/Other?) and how you're running your program (Command line, debugger, other?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *charArray1 = "ThisHasAColonAtTheEnd:";`
```

Here you point charArray1 to a string literal. In C, you cannot modify a literal. See e.g [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c)

You can store the string in an array which you can modify. So just do

```
char charArray1[] = "ThisHasAColonAtTheEnd:";
```

Comment: @QuinnLiu Next time **turn on compiler warnings and pay attention to them.** You should have gotten a warning when assigning a string literal to a non-const `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be that your string is allocated in read only area so you cannot change it. Fist copy and edit a copy.

BTW. Depending on a compiler and execution environment it might actually work - on some embedded systems for example.