# What is the difference in pointers when defining char and int?

Tags: c++, pointers

I understand the basics of how pointers work, but the following example confuses me.

```
int *myNum = 10; // Produces an error

char *myChar = "Something"; // Works fine
```

Why does assigning char work but integer doesn't (Maybe cause char is treated as an array)?

As well what confuses me when directly assigning a pointer variable, does it automatically get an address?

```
char *myChar = "Something";
```

and

```
char myChar = "Something";
char *charAddr = &myChar;
```

What would be the difference here, or equals?

Comment: `char myChar = "Something";` does not work, because `"Something"` is not a char.

Comment: What you're looking for is [Array to pointer conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: @immibis ITYM `"Something"` is not implicitly convertible to `char`.  `char myChar = 5.5;` is legal

Comment: I think you are simply confusing single quotes and double quotes. `int *myNum = 10; ` is wrong the same way as `char *myChar = 'A';`. Single quotes surround chars; double quotes surround constant arrays of chars, also known as C string literals. That said, `char *myChar = "Something";` is only half right, as others pointed out. Strict compilers will demand that you declare `const char *myChar`, since you cannot write to elements in the array pointed to by `myChar` on modern architectures.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
"Something"
```

is essentially short for:

```
static const char some_hidden_array[] = {'S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
some_hidden_array
```

That is, when you write `"Something"`, the compiler generates an array behind the scenes, and gives you a pointer to the start of that array. Since this is already a pointer to a char, you'll have no problem assigning it to a variable of type "pointer to a char" (written as `char*`).

```
10
```

is *not* short for anything similar. It's just the number 10 - it's not a pointer to an array containing the number 10, or anything like that.

Note that a `char` is a *single character*, not a string, which is why the string syntax is unusual compared to most other types - a string is *several* chars, not just one. If you try to use a plain old `char`, you'll see the same thing:

```
char *myChar = 'a'; // error
```

or for any other type:

```
float *myFloat = 42.1f; // error
```

In other words, it's not strange that `10` gives an error - if anything, it's strange that `"Something"` *doesn't*. (At least, it's strange until you know how string literals work)

Answer (score 10):

It's the same thing (no magic from the compiler is happening). By default, literals like 10 are int values, not int*.

You need to cast:

```
int *myNum = (int*)10; // Need to cast
char *myChar = "Something"; // No need to cast "..." is already a char*
```

Note that it's dangerous to reference a pointer to absolute value like this because you will end up with the address 10 in CPU memory.

Regarding your second question, "..." is treated as a contiguous sequence of char in memory similar to array and equivalent to char*.

For a thoughtful understanding of C, pointers and differences between arrays and pointers, you should read this: Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets by Peter van der Linden.

Comment: Thank you! As for second question, I meant more like if those 2 equal? Is first example a shorter way of getting the address? Thanks!

Comment: Remember to select this as your accepted answer if it answered your question.

Comment: `"..."` is not a `char*`. And I wouldn't recommend a C book for learning C++; the idioms are entirely different.

Comment: @J.Doe No, the second example simply doesn't work. A string literal is *not* a `char`, it's a `char[]`. Changing that, taking the address of a `char[]` will give you a pointer to a pointer - in this case, a pointer to a stack variable, so only defined until the scope exits. This is quite important, since string literals are a bit of magic - they appear "local", but don't actually have a scope; the original pointer is valid everywhere,  the pointer to a pointer isn't.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does assigning char work but integer doesn't (Maybe cause char is treated as an array)?

You are right, `"Something"` is a string literal and can be treated as char array. After `char *myChar = "Something";` the following thing happen: it is allocated *length+1* bytes of memory where `"Something"` will be stored, `myChar` is pointed to the starting address of this memory. String literals are somewhat special.

Here is a general way of initializing array with constant values:

```
// valid initializations;
char s2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
char s1[] = "123";
```

> As well what confuses me when directly assigning a pointer variable, does it automatically get an address?

Yes.

Take a look at [8.5.2 Character arrays of c++ docs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf#page=216)

Answer (score 2):

When you do `char *myChar = "Something";`, you create a read-only string literal somewhere in the memory, which ends in a null character. Now this is something special with the compiler, that it interprets a chunk of 'char' variables stored continuously and ending with a null character as string. So basically you created an array of characters, and when you do `*myChar*`, it returns the string.

In case of integers or any other data types, it differentiates between `int *ptr` as a pointer to an integer, and `int ptr` as an integer. You are getting an error probably because the address you entered may not be valid/available to you.

Also, doing

```
char myChar = "Something";  //this is an error, since char can hold one character
char *charAddr = &myChar;
```

Note that `myChar` and `&myChar` are the same, since `myChar` is a pointer!

Edit: Refer here about string literals:
[Is it possible to modify a string of char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for explanation, so does type *var = something, always create a read-only variable in memory? And as per second question, I more meant like if those 2 are equal (shorter way) :) Thanks!

Comment: @J.Doe Yes. Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c

Comment: Thank you, this does help a lot.

Comment: @J.Doe no, `type *var = something` does not create a read-only variable.  It is only the string literal `"Something"` which is read-only  (and it is not a variable)

Answer (score 1):

While theoretically the first `int *myNum = 10` makes sense—especially if you know there is a useful `int` at address ten—in general it is rarely useful and potentially quite dangerous.

However, there are certain pointer assignments which are widely used and quite safe:

```
int *myNum = 0;
```

On 99.9+% of modern CPU architectures, this is the same as

```
int *myNum = NULL;
```

See the definition of NULL in `<stddef.h>` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stddef.h.html).

As a general rule, assignment of pointer variables is best done by setting to the address of something else.

```
int k, *p = &k;
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm so basically, int *myNum = 10 // Pointer to an address "10" and not actually an address that contains a variable int with a value of 10?

Comment: `int *myNum = 0;` is the same as `int *myNum = NULL;` on all systems. It makes a null pointer.  You're getting mixed up with the fact that null pointer might not be represented by all-bits-zero (which makes no difference to this code)

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, and your confusion is pretty much exactly why you need to add the explicit cast to make this compile - this is almost always a *mistake*, rather than the intended behaviour. On a modern desktop/server system, you really don't want to use pointers to manually picked addresses. It was useful in the past, though - for example, for direct access to graphics memory (or any other kind of device, really). With hardware abstraction, there's very few legitimate uses (outside of the rather obvious `0`/`NULL` case, which per C standard *always* works :)).