# Modifying an array of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I know when we declared a `char *c ="Hello";` means that we cannot modify this string. But how come I was able to modify this array of string in C.

```
char *p [] = {"Hello","World"}; 
*p = "Mode";
```

Should not that give me an error for attempting to modify it?

Comment: Take a look at this answer it is quite good to understand the concept of strings. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1011545/2555668

Comment: @irqed This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: @Lundin this is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @AbdulazizAsiri No it isn't. If you understood the differences between an array, a pointer, and an array of pointers, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that if the OP understood arrays of pointers we wouldn't be here, but it is different. That question never mentions an array of pointers. It only compares `char *s = "abc"` to `char s[] = "abc"`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If you understand that `char* p` is a pointer and `char arr[]` is an array, then you should be able to tell `char*p []` is an array of pointers. Which is something completely unrelated to modifying string literals...

Answer (score 6):

You're not modifying a string (literal) anywhere.

```
 char *p [] = {"Hello","World"};
```

Here [`p` is an array (size 2) of pointer-to-`char`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*p+%5B%5D). It's a variable, there's nothing read-only about it. The strings it currently points to however are read-only.

```
*p = "Mode";
```

You're simply changing the first element of that array to point to a different (read-only) string. This is the same as:

```
p[0] = "Mode";
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` is an array of pointers.These pointers are modifiable,however their targets(the things they point to) are not.

`*p` is equivalent to `p[0]` which is the first pointer in the array.

`*p = "Mode"` modify the value of the pointer `p[0]`,not the string literal `"hello"`.

Comment: I don't see that this answer adds anything that my answer didn't already say.