# Why modifying a string with different ways have different behaviors?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, string-literals

Why these two code snippets have different behaviors

```
char p[] = "hello";
p[0] = 'W'; //works fine
```

While this gives a `segmentation fault`

```
char *ptr = "hello"; 
ptr[0] = 'W'; // undefined behavior
```

What is the difference between both codes,why i am unable to modify the string using pointer?

Comment: The first one does not modify a literal. It modifies array `p` which you formed by copying a literal.

Comment: You can add [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) to the duplicates of this question.

Comment: or this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011455/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-string-of-char-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second case,

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

`ptr` points to a *string literal*. You cannot modify the content of a *string literal*. Period. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> [..] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

In contrast, first case is creating an **array** and **initializing** using that a string literal. The array is perfectly modifiable. You're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The first code initialized an array and modifying its element is completely legal because the array is not `const` and `p[0]` is a valid index.

The second code is modifying string literals pointed by the pointer. It will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.4.5 String literals:

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.