# How can I return list in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to divide the string with *, and return the divided strings, as follows.

```
abc*d*efg*hijk -> [abc,d,efg,hijk]
```

This is my code, where *pattern is the given string, and I first count the number of asterisk(cnt), and make a empty list with length cnt. But it keeps getting the error and I don't get it... Can anyone help me?

error message

1. value computed is not used (*star_cnt++;)
2. function returns address of local variable(return units;)
   Number 2 is my main error. I can't return the list

```
int Slice(char *pattern) {

  int *star_cnt;
  int cnt;

  *star_cnt = *pattern;
  cnt = 0;

  while (*star_cnt != '\0') {
    if (*star_cnt == '*') {
      cnt++;
    }
    *star_cnt++;
  }

  int units[cnt];
  int *unit;
  int unit_cnt;
  unit_cnt = 0;
  *unit = *pattern;

  while (*unit != '\0') {
    int *new_unit;
    while (*unit != '*'){
      *new_unit = *unit;
      unit++;
      new_unit++;
    }
    unit++;
    units[unit_cnt] = *new_unit;
  }
  return units;
```

Comment: `*star_cnt = *pattern;` That's undefined behaviour. `star_cnt` is an unintialised pointer. Same for `*unit = *pattern;`

Comment: *it keeps getting the error*. It would make sense to show the actual error. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67119324/edit) the question to include the error and also provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ensure you also provide the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Don't tag a question asking for "returning a list in C" with the [tag:c++] tag.  It annoys people and attracts downvotes.

Comment: for Jin000000: The C language does not define what a list is. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and read wikipage about [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Document how you choose to represent lists, and for your next question provide some [mre] - with a `main`; maybe you want to use [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) but they are not a list

Comment: 1) `*star_cnt = *pattern;` should be `star_cnt = pattern;`. Same idea for `*unit = *pattern;` You want to copy the pointer. 2) `int units[cnt]; ... return units;` This is incorrect. You're returning a pointer to memory that ceases to exist when the function returns. You need to `malloc` the necessasry memory.

Comment: Re "*The C language does not define what a list is*", @Basile Starynkevitch, To what are you replying?!

Comment: If you want to return an array of strings take a look at how `main` receives arguments - it's exactly an array of strings... Something like: `char ** func(...)`

Comment: I am trying to understand the comments one by one and for sure, I am editing my question in more friendly way. It might take time, but thank you so much for answering!

Comment: Jin000000: You may want to use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Once your code has no warnings, use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger then [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to understand better the behavior of your executable. You could also download then study for inspiration the source code of existing [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: Jin000000: read also some recent C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better. It gives you usual terminology. Of course read documentation of your compiler and of your debugger.

Comment: I posted another answer please take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I felt there were a number of things wrong, and that looking at a working example might actually help a bit more here.

You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * @fn Slice()
 * @param [IN] pattern  - pointer to string to be analysed
 * @param 
 * @return pointer to array for strings, array is terminated by NULL
 * */
char** Slice(char *pattern) {

  char *star_cnt;
  int cnt;
  char** resultlist;

  star_cnt = pattern;
  cnt = 0;

  while (*star_cnt != '\0') {
    if (*star_cnt == '*') {
      cnt++;
    }
    star_cnt++;
  }

  printf("%d items\n",cnt+1);

  resultlist = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (cnt+2));
  memset(resultlist,0,sizeof(char*) * (cnt+2));
  star_cnt = pattern;

  cnt = 0;  
  resultlist[cnt] = star_cnt;
  //printf("item %d: %s\n",cnt,resultlist[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  while (*star_cnt != '\0') {
    if (*star_cnt == '*') {
      *star_cnt = '\0';
      resultlist[cnt] = star_cnt+1;
      //printf("item %d: %s\n",cnt,resultlist[cnt]);
      cnt++;
    }
    star_cnt++;
  }
  return resultlist;
}

int main()
{
  char working_string[] = "abc*d*efg*hijk";
  char* backup_string = strdup(working_string);
  char** list = NULL;
   
  list = Slice(working_string);
  int i;

  i = 0;
  if (list != NULL)
  {
    while(list[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d : %s\n",i,list[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(list);
  }

  printf("original_string = %s\n",backup_string);
  free(backup_string);
}
```

It produces an output like this:

```
4 items
0 : abc
1 : d
2 : efg
3 : hijk
original_string = abc*d*efg*hijk
```

The Slice function basically returns a pointer to char* strings, and the array list is terminated with a NULL in the last element. Keep in mind that in this solution the original string is modified so it cannot be used again.

Comment: I wanted to change this code to not modify the original string, and I tried several options.
My personal best try was pattern_copy = strcpy(pattern_copy, pattern); list = Slice(pattern_copy); , but this gives me core dumped error... Would you mind giving me some hints about changing the code?

Comment: According to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743877/can-a-string-literal-in-c-be-modified] modifying string literals is unidentified behavior in C.  Please either remove your answer or correct it.

Comment: @Jin000000 According to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743877/can-a-string-literal-in-c-be-modified] modifying string literals is unidentified behavior in C.  This answer might work but it is not a correct answer. Please unaccept this answer.

Comment: I am really Sorry, my bad, it appears as if ```char test[] = "abc*d*efg*hijk";"``` is mutable.  I want to change my vote but system does not allow that unless you edit your answer. so please, please edit it so I can reverse my vote.

Comment: @Jin000000 I am really Sorry, my bad, it appears as if ```char test[] = "abc*d*efg*hijk";"``` is mutable.

Comment: @Jin000000 rather use strdup() to make a backup copy of the string. I have modified the answer slightly to make a backup of the original string.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer. I up-voted it

Answer (score 1):

For storing and returning the result you can also define string container like:

```
struct c_str_container{
    char **arr;
    size_t size;
};
```

And then you can define functions like `init_c_str_container`, `add_element_to_c_str_container` and `free_c_str_container` for dealing with the container.

then you can write the `substrings` function with using  [`strchr`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm) function for finding the delimiters and splitting the string in to sub-strings.

Finally you can use this function to create the container and then after displaying the result from the container (and possibly doing other things with the container) you free the allocated memory by the predefined function `free_c_str_container`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct c_str_container{
    char **arr;
    size_t size;
};

void init_c_str_container(struct c_str_container *container){
    container->arr = NULL;
    container->size = 0;
}

int add_element_to_c_str_container(struct c_str_container *container, const char *txt, size_t length){
    char **newarr = (char **) realloc(container->arr, (container->size + 1) * (sizeof(char *)));
    if(!newarr){
        newarr =  (char **) malloc((container->size + 1) * (sizeof(char *)));
        if(!newarr){
            return -1;
        }else{
            for(size_t counter = container->size; counter--;){
                newarr[counter] = container->arr[counter];
            }
            if(container->size){
                free(container->arr);
            }
        }
    }
    newarr[container->size] = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(newarr[container->size], txt, length);
    newarr[container->size][length] = '\0';
    container->arr = newarr;
    ++container->size;
    return 0;
}

void free_c_str_container(struct c_str_container *container){
    for(size_t counter = container->size; counter--;){
        free(container->arr[counter]);
    }
    free(container->arr);
    container->size = 0;
}


struct c_str_container substrings(const char *input, const char delimiter){
    const char *input_end = input + strlen(input);
    struct c_str_container container;
    init_c_str_container(&container);

    while(strchr(input, delimiter) == input){
        ++input;
    }

    const char *end_point;
    while((end_point = strchr(input, delimiter))){
        add_element_to_c_str_container(&container, input, (end_point - input));
        while(strchr(end_point, delimiter) == end_point){
            ++end_point;
        }
        input = end_point;
    }

    if(input < input_end){
        add_element_to_c_str_container(&container, input, (input_end - input));
    }

    return container;
}

int main(void) {

    struct c_str_container container = substrings("***as***we*grow*up", '*');

    printf("number of elements is : %zu\n", container.size);
    for(size_t counter = 0; counter < container.size; ++counter){
        printf("element %zu is : %s\n", counter, container.arr[counter]);
    }
    free_c_str_container(&container);
    printf("now elements are : %zu\n", container.size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

for the test string =`"***as***we*grow*up"` delimeter = `'*'` the result of the program is:

```
number of elements is : 4
element 0 is : as
element 1 is : we
element 2 is : grow
element 3 is : up
now elements are : 0
```